# Would $5000 be enough for this trip in 2014 december?

Tags: planning

- Tokyo ( 5 days) - Disneyland, temples, fish markets, sumo fight, tokyo city, gardens, food, mount fuji, japanese car shows.
- London (4 days) - Big Ben, London Eye, Buckingham Palace, attractions near there.
- Paris by train from London ( 3 days) - Eiffel tower, attractions near the city, disneyland paris, food, Notre Dame, Arc de Triomphe.
- Los Angeles (7 days) - Disneyland, Downtown LA, Universal studios, Hollywood walk of fame, Hollywood Boulevard.
- New York ( 1 week and 2 days) - Going to be there for new years - NYE ball drop, Statue of Liberty, Empire State Building, Central park, Times Square, Rockefeller Center, The Brooklyn Bridge, Coney island.

NOTE : Willing to eat from fast food places, but eating at a nice restaurant whilst in paris at least once. Will at least buy one small souvenir for each place I visit. Will go clothes shopping in America ( i heard its cheap - nothing too expensive just discounts). I'm mostly interested in having fun, taking lots of photos, so not going all out, willing to stay at decent motels, hotels - doesn't have to be 5 star. So do you think 5000 will be enough ( including flights which are $2000). That's my budget as I'm already going to a trip around Europe with my friend this year in July which costs me a lot - with contiki. This trip I want to do with my bf on our own.

It can only be around 1 month as he can't get more time off work. $5000 each. It's both my bf and I. We will be splitting hotel prices in half.

Comment: Staying in Hostels or Couchsurfing - Yes.  Staying in 5 star hotels - No.  The real answer is probably somewhere in the middle, but with the details given there's no way to know.

Comment: The best way to not spend too much money would be to take your time to travel around the world, you'll save on plane tickets and enjoy the places you go.

Answer (score 5):

So you have $3000 (each) after flights?

I can only really speak for Tokyo, London and Paris (never been Stateside), but very rough costs would be something like:

**Tokyo**

*Food*: Depends on the time of year, but you can easily eat each day for around ¥2500 (~$25) if you stick to the cheapest places, around ¥5000 ($50) if you have a reasonably nice 'evening meal' and the sky's the limit if you want to eat well.

*Hotel*: The cheapest hotels can be as low as $50 a night for 2 if you search (so 5 nights = $250 for 2) though I'd budget more than that (say $100 a night) as a minimum if you travel peak, want to be more central or want breakfast included. Hotels.com is a great place to start.

*Attractions*: Disneyland is quite expensive (around $60 for a 1 day passport), and sumo (for a good seat) is around the same. The main car show is something like $30 to get in. Temples are usually free, as is Tsukiji fish market, gardens are usually ¥300-800 (around $8, say $30 total).

*Transport*: (Assuming you skip bullet trains and the like) local travel adds up, particularly down to Mt Fuji, so I'd budget around $20 a day for that, and maybe $20 contingency (total $120).

***Total***: For 5 days with some breathing room per person: meals $250, hotel $250, attractions $120, transport $120 = $740.

**London**

*Food*: Another world city, with everything from cheap takeaway food to 3 Michelin star restaurants. From my experience London has fewer 'low to mid-range' restaurants than Tokyo, and a lot more tourist traps, so I'd suggest a little more here, around $60 per day (though of course you can survive on sandwiches and fast food for much less than that - this assumes a decent evening meal with drinks at around $30 per head)

*Hotel*: All depends where in London you want to stay, but there are budget chains all over the place (Premier Inn, Travelodge) with decent, clean (but small) rooms available from $100 a night when on special offer. Again, to be on the safe side I'd set aside a little more, say $150 per room per night. So 4 nights = $600 ($300 each)

*Attractions*: The big commercial London attractions aren't cheap - the London Eye is around $30 - but most public museums and art galleries are free (except for special exhibitions). You can also get some combined tickets which offset the cost, and cheaper tickets if you buy online in advance. If you plan on doing a lot, you're probably looking at around $120 per person total for a mix of different attractions.

*Transport*:  A 1 day Travelcard on the Underground is around $12. Alternatively you can get an Oyster card which you 'top up' with cash. On any given day, regardless of the number of journeys, you'll never be charged more than the equivalent 1 day travel card - so say $50 for 4 days.

***Total***: For 4 days with some breathing room per person: meals $240, hotel $300, attractions $120, transport $50 = $710.

**Paris**

*Food*: As with London and Tokyo, it all depends on how well you want to eat. Street stands, cheap pizza places and studenty-buffet all you can eat deals are all available, as is *haute cuisine* and more exotic fayre. When I last went we had coffee and croissants for breakfast (~$10), a sit down lunch set (~$20) and usually the 'fixed menu' dinner with some wine (~$30). It all depends on your definition of 'nice' however - good wine plus 3 a la carte courses could easily set you back $100+ per head.

*Hotel*: I last stayed in a private room in a hostel, which was around $20 per night. Hotels are like London - there are chains of budget hotels in lesser known districts with rooms from $70 per night, and there are the chains of luxury hotels for $400 per night. I'd budget $150 per room per night for a 3 star.

*Attractions*: Unfortunately many of Paris' museums and art galleries require a ticket (unlike the U.K.), as do most of the major attractions you mention. However, some churches and similar venues are free / donation only. Disneyland is ridiculously expensive at around $65. I'd say $150 inc. Disneyland is a good estimate.

*Transport*: Paris is a lovely city to walk around, and it's also a cheap way to see the sights - soaking up the atmosphere is part of the fun. Alternatively there are numerous passes, starting at around $13 for inner city, 1 day (zones 1-3) on the Metro / buses etc. Eurostar to Paris can be pricey, but booked in advance starts at around $70 1 way.

***Total***: For 3 days with some breathing room per person: meals $180, hotel $225, attractions $150, transport $100 = $675.

For these three then: **$2125**.

I imagine LA is comparable to the three cities above, however the big cost from your itinerary seems to be NYC at New Year. If it's anything like my home city (Edinburgh) the costs of everything skyrocket - hotels, food, drinks, the whole lot. Check this out thoroughly before you go.

Of course, there will be other expenses (souvenirs, bottled water or drinks, airport transfers, unexpected big nights out that just happen, and all manner of other costs) that are hard to accurately estimate. When I plan travel I usually include a hefty contingency fund.

**In summary**, I think $3000 is at the budget end of the spectrum, requiring a bit of booking, investigation and money savvy!

Hope this helps, and enjoy your travels!

Sources: personal experience, hotel booking sites, travel booking sites attraction sites